# simple ajax call , no syntax errors. still not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the file which sends ajax request.

```
 function ju(id)
  {
     alert("into");
     $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url: "trial2.php",
     data: { flag1: id},
     success: function(result) {
         alert(result);
       },
     complete:function(){
        alert("over");
        }
    });
     }  


     ju("yoyo::");

     </script>
```

the trial2.php is this. simply returning what ever it received.

```
    session_start();

     $resultstring = "yoyo :: " . $_POST['flag1'];

    echo $resultstring;
```

?>

but only the "into" alert is coming. after this the page just stops working.  no alerts nothing. whats wrong in this?? i have done a bit of ajax things in past, but never came accross this.

Comment: Do you get value of id in you function?

Comment: First, add an `error:` handler to your Ajax function to see if an error is being reported.  Second, look in the network tab of the browser debugger to see exactly what is being sent over the network to the server and then received back over the network from the server.  These two things should show you exactly what is actually happening and then you can act accordingly based on what you learn.

Comment: Have you included jQuery library before calling that function??

Comment: oops my bad.. :P i included, but a wrong library. sorry guys..

Answer (score 1):

You send an array to your php code as data , so you have to write

```
$data =  $_POST['data'];
```

// $data is an array contain your flag1 .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding an error callback to the ajax call to help narrow down the problem.

```
function ju(id)
{
   console.debug("into");
   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: "trial2.php",
     data: { flag1: id},
     success: function(result) {
       console.debug(result);
     },
     complete:function(){
       console.debug("over");
     },
     error: function(xhr, error){
       console.debug(xhr); 
       console.debug(error);
     }
   });
}
```